# how to subscribe to observable in child component angular2?

Tags: angular, observable, ngrx, ngrx-store

I'm getting an `undefined value` error when subscribing to an observable in a child component. What is the correct way to subscribe to it?

I tried to use ngOnChanges but I get the store observable there and I don't want to bind the store to the child component

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can pass the result value using the async pipe like this :

```
[data]="vhqEndpointOptions$ | async"
```

and then you won't have to manage the subscription and just get the array value.

if you need the observable you can use a setter for the @Input :

```
@Input("data") 
set Data(value:Observable<any[]>){
  if(value){
    value.subscribe(...);
  }
}
```